# Running React app with node.js and nginx server on 3rd level domain

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I have an express node.js app running on my server. Used by nginx
The app uses https with a free letsencrypt certificate.

URL: https://178.20.42.150.sslip.io

Now I want to connect a third level domain:
http://criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io

Accordingly, it is without https, it suits me at the moment.

I have configured Nginx:

```
 server {
            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io www.criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
                client_max_body_size 100m;
                client_body_timeout 600s;
                client_body_in_file_only clean;
                client_body_buffer_size 16K;
                proxy_connect_timeout 70;
                proxy_send_timeout 90;
                proxy_read_timeout 90;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                }
        }
```

Opened ports 3006, 3010 for testing.
And I have my second app (React) running by
URL: https://178.20.42.150.sslip.io
and proxied to
proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;

But I want to run together with Rect app and node.js server together. I did it successfully on a completely different project. There, when testing on a local PC, I ran:

"cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently "npm run server" "npm run client""

client Rect started like this:
"start": "set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start",

Client / package.json had:
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
And the server had PORT 3000

everything worked fine.

But now for a third-level domain, in order to redirect it to another application, I proxy it to nginx criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io on 3000 port.

After all sorts of experiments, I get:

if the server is started on port 3000, it will not start, because this port is already taken by the client React. I start the server on port 3010.
If you remove "proxy": "http: // localhost: 3000" in the client React package.json, then the client React application will start (by the way, after manipulations like this: delete package-lock.json in client and server and re-do npm in both projects install), but the link between client and server does not work. They work separately.

Checked the server:
http://criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io:3010/test   works

If you do not remove "proxy": "http: // localhost: 3000" in client React package.json, then client React will output:
“Invalid Host header”

Console at startup when in client \ package.json:
"proxy": "http: // localhost: 3010"

Console :

```
128|reactc | [0] App
128|reactc | [1]
128|reactc | [1] > example@0.1.0 start /var/www/criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io/html/client
128|reactc | [1] > set PORT=3006 && react-scripts start
128|reactc | [1]
128|reactc | [0] WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
128|reactc | [0] WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
128|reactc | [0] development mode
128|reactc | [0] App has been started on port 3010...
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://0.0.0.0:3000/
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /var/www/criptoarbitr.178.20.42.150.sslip.io/html/client/public
128|reactc | [1] ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
128|reactc | [1] Starting the development server...
128|reactc | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | Compiled with warnings.
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | src/components/Chart.js
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1] Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
128|reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze  | [1]
```

Main nginx file 178.20.42.150.sslip.io:

```
server {

        root /var/www/178.20.42.150.sslip.io/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name 178.20.42.150.sslip.io www.178.20.42.150.sslip.io;

        location / {
                    # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
client_max_body_size 100m;
client_body_timeout 600s;
client_body_in_file_only clean;
client_body_buffer_size 16K;
proxy_connect_timeout 70;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
proxy_read_timeout 90;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header host $host;
proxy_set_header X-real-ip $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-forward-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/178.20.42.150.sslip.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/178.20.42.150.sslip.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}server {
    if ($host = www.178.20.42.150.sslip.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = 178.20.42.150.sslip.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name 178.20.42.150.sslip.io www.178.20.42.150.sslip.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Experimenting GitHub: https://github.com/illusionoff/reactcriptoarbitr_test_squeeze

```
Can you make them work together on a 3rd level domain name?
```